# get browser Locale

Tags: java, servlets

I have a question about the browser Locale. In pricipal, the request.getLocale retrieve the locale from the user's OS. I would like to retrieve the browser Locale independent of user's OS. 
The web site has multiable languages (german, italy, english), so that user can switch language manually. 
In the html page, there are meta element which show the difference.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="de" />
```

"de" will be changed to en or other language due to user's click.

The question is whether there is a way to retieve this info in java servlet.

Update:
In my LogoutServlet doPost method, I have a logout method which should retrieve the current language from html page of browser.

```
String locale =request.getLocale().getDisplayLanguage();
```

It doesn't change to Fr or IT based on the content-language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer that could solve one part of your question:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/442889/JSP/java/Reading-META-tag-Servlet

You need to collect the meta tag's data using clientside script and send them to your servlet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

function metaKeywords() {  

metaCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');  
alert('');  
for (i=0;i<metaCollection.length;i++) {  
var nameAttribute = metaCollection[i].name.search(/foo/);  

if (nameAttribute!= -1) {  
alert(metaCollection[i].content);  
}  
}  
}  
>
</script>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get meta info in Servlet in java. because I want to retrieve this language for example "de" for sendRedirect method. in doPost method

Comment: you may want to send metaCollection to your servlet by using ajax

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, browsers don't *have* a locale independent of the OS.

You're giving users a way to manually choose languages (great!). To know what language they've chosen, you'll need to do something to send that information back to your server. A cookie would probably be the simplest way, since it will accompany every request. (Keep it small, though, for that same reason.)